# Make shell prompt show current head when in a VCS

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs, command-prompt

When using a VCS, (I use Mercurial and Git in Linux, Bash prompt), is there any way to have the prompt show the current head or tag in the directory?

More than once I have shot myself in the foot by working in one head when thinking I was in another, for example, pushing v0.3 to testing when they needed v.02, or patching bugs in `dev` then they needed to be patched in `prod`, or vice versa.

Comment: Which Prompt? MS-DOS? Bash? Csh? Zsh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git provides a bash function that shows the current branch or hash if headless. Look for __git_ps1 in the [bash_completion](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash) file.

My `~/.bashrc` contains these lines:

```sh
Green='\[\e[0;32m\]'
BIGreen='\[\e[1;92m\]'
Color_Off='\[\e[0m\]'
export PS1=$Green'\w $(__git_ps1 "(%s)")'$BIGreen'$ '$Color_Off
```

which will create a prompt like this:

```
~/repos/myproject (master)$
```

Answer (score 9):

For Mercurial, there is [hg-prompt](http://stevelosh.com/projects/hg-prompt/) by Steve Losh. This is an extension for Mercurial that gives you a new `hg prompt` command. You put a call to this command into your `PS1` environment variable:

```
export PS1='\u in \w`hg prompt "{on {branch}}{status}{update}" 2>/dev/null` $'
```

to get a prompt like

```
user in ~/src/project on feature-branch? $
```

where the `?` at the end tells you that there is an unknown file in your repository.

Steve wrote a [blog post about his Zsh prompt](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/) and there are more colorful prompts from the documentation:

[image: Steve's colorful prompts]

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [git-prompt](https://github.com/lvv/git-prompt). It describes itself as a "bash prompt with GIT, SVN and HG modules".

Just for git you can do it much easier though: simply load the bash-completion module (simply `source git-completion.bash` - you'll find the file somewhere in the git source tree or if you installed git using your package manager in whatever folder it puts bash completion modules) of git and use `__git_ps1` in your prompt, e.g. via `export PS1='w$(__git_ps1 "(%s)") > '`

Comment: thanks! the git-completion.bash is quite nice.  tried git-prompt and did not care for it as much - although I liked the attitude of the authors on the home page.  guess hg will need to be vinalla prompt.

Answer (score 1):

It's worth taking a look at http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/02/my-extravagant-zsh-prompt/. Git and Mercurial, plus a load of other information.

Even if you don't want his exact prompt it provides a lot of information on how he built it up.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at http://vcprompt.com/. It's written in Python, cross-platform, and you can simply download it and drop it into your bin directory. It supports bzr, cvs, darcs, fossil, git, hg and svn.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Mercurial bash prompt:

```
function parse_hg_branch {
  _hg_id=`hg id 2> /dev/null`
  _hg_id="$_hg_id `hg id -nb 2> /dev/null`"
  echo $_hg_id
  unset _hg_id
}

function proml {
  local LIGHT_RED="\[\033[1;31m\]"
  local     BROWN="\[\033[0;33m\]"
  local     GREEN="\[\033[0;32m\]"
  local      CYAN="\[\033[0;36m\]"
  local   DEFAULT="\[\033[0m\]"

  PS1="$LIGHT_RED\u@$BROWN\h:$GREEN\w $CYAN\$(parse_hg_branch) $DEFAULT\$ "
}
proml
```

Which expands to something like this:

```
fred@bedrock:~ e65381b0ed42+ tip 0+ default $
```